# Grails Helloworld tutorial app not working

Tags: grails

I feel guilty coming to Stack Exchange with such a trivial issue, but I've been banging my head against it all morning and can't seem to get anywhere.  I am trying to run the simple HelloWorld app in the Grails tutorial: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#creatingAnApplication

I have Grails installed, I can run it, create the controller and everything, but no matter what page I hit, I get nothing but a blank.  Even pages that don't exist, return a blank page and not an error.

For example, I tried http: //localhost:8080/helloworld, obviously, and get nothing but a blank page back.  The same thing happens for http: //localhost:8080/hellowrld, http: //localhost:8080/helphelphelp and http: //localhost:8080/pleasefortheloveofpeteworkalready.  Always the empty response.

When I try a different port, I get an error.  When I stop-app and try, I get an error.  When I run grails run-app with port 9090 and try port 8080, I get an error, but on 9090, I get the blank page.  So, I assume the server is fielding the requests, but just isn't responding for some reason.

I'm probably missing something super simple, something dumb, but I can't figure out what it is, and the complete lack of feedback is killing me.

Are there logs anywhere I can check?  And, is there something obvious I'm missing?

(PS: I assume the environment vars are correct, because I can run Grails no problem.  Also, I installed, but never ran, the GGST IDE thing.  I rebooted since then, but could that have installed some service that's taking over?)

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Hey, small internet world!  I've been working today on updating a grails app I wrote last year and was looking on SO for something related to that.

Comment: Hmm, I usually use Eclipse/GGTS, which automates things like managing the environment.  Logging should happen on the console, but is normally set to error -- maybe you can try modifying the log4j element in Config.groovy from error to info and see if that gets you some more information.

Comment: What you got in the stacktrace.log file? Or some exceptions thrown in the run-time?

Comment: And why is there an extra blank ' ' in your url: `http: //localhost:8080/hellowrld`?

Answer (score 4):

The application name is the default "context", so if you create an application called foo (`grails create-app foo`) it will be available at `http://localhost:8080/foo` if you run `grails run-app`. You can use a different port, for example 9090, by running `grails -Dserver.port=9090 run-app` and you can also use a different context (or none at all).

The `run-app` script displays the full URL of the application in the output window - you should see something like:

```
Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/helloworld
```

Comment: -1 @BurtBeckwith What Risser got is not 404 page but a blank one, so I think he is clear about what you stated above. Maybe it is caused by some environment issues?

Comment: Jinzhao Wu - have you tried this before? If you request a context that doesn't exist in the Tomcat that Grails configures you get a blank page. If you request an unknown page within a valid context you get a 404.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I went through the steps the OP described and got it all right. The only difference I saw there is an extra blank in his url after `http:`. So I don't understand why did you mention context as a potential issue.

Comment: Because he got a blank page :)

Comment: You will find the context in application.properties. Try other tutorials. http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners/